# Generalized envelope theorems

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I'm looking for references for two generalizations of Danskin/envelope-type theorems for convex optimization. The first is for when the parameters are functions on a space rather than numbers. A simple example would be understanding how the value function locally depends on $g(x)$ for, say, a linear program with the objective function:
$$
\max_{f(x)} \int f(x) g(x) dx
$$
and some similarly defined constraints that could be pointwise or integrated and for some suitably nice class of functions, $f$.

Second, I'm interested about what, if anything, one can say about the derivatives of the argmax correspondence (rather than the value function) given a convex optimization with an objective function and inequality and equality constraints that all depend on a continuous set of parameters, say on an open neighborhood where argmax is a function rather than a correspondence?